# Getting Views to use custom aliases

Tags: views, path-aliases

I have the following custom URL aliases that point to specific Views paths:

- /california/los-angeles maps to /locations/los-angeles
- /username/listing/post maps to /item/post

Views still uses the older, pre-defined aliases. Is there any way to get Views to respect the custom aliases I've set? I'd need to do this at a global level, as there are too many paths to be changed in Views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module will fix this right out of the box.

Once enabled, it'll make sure there is only one canonical path available: your custom one. So all mentions of `locations/los-angeles` created by Drupal will be replaced with `california/los-angeles`, so that if you try to access `locations/los-angeles` it'll redirect to `california/los-angeles`.